# Using greater than or less than in a Rails Active Record query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

**Questions** have_many **question_tags**.

How can I get all **questions** that:

1. Have a **question_tag** with name "javascript"
2. Are not answered
3. Have more than 2 "vote_count"?

Here are the tables:

```
Questions
  is_answered:boolean
  vote_count:integer

QuestionTags
  name:string
  question_id:integer
```

This is the query I have so far. It does #1 and #2. **How can I do #3?**

```
Question.joins(:question_tags).where(question_tags: {name: "javascript"}, question: {is_answered: false})
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This looks like a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11317662/rails-using-greater-than-less-than-with-a-where-statement). What you want is the string or array syntax for [where](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods.html#method-i-where).

```
Question.joins(:question_tags).where(question_tags: {name: "javascript"}, is_answered: false).where(["#{Question.table_name}.vote_count > ?", 2])
```

Updated to include the table name in the last where clause.

Comment: For the "where vote_count" clause, how can I make it specfically on the "jobs" table?

I couldn't figure out how to use that syntax with the joins() query, which is why it's not a duplicate.

Comment: I'll assume you mean the Questions table: `.where(["#{Question.table_name}.vote_count > ?", 2])`. If you really mean jobs then put `Job` instead of `Question` when getting the table_name.